# Simple app to buzz the watch when it gets disconnected from phone

Tags: zeppos

I would like a simple app that periodically checks the bluetooth connection between the phone and my watch (GTR 3 Pro), and buzzes the watch when it gets disconnected from my phone.  This will be useful if I accidentally leave my phone somewhere and walk away from it, or my phone gets stolen or something like that.

```
Some previous amazfit watches had this feature built-in, but it doesn't seem to be available in my GTR 3 Pro right now.  Thank you.
```

Answer (score 1):

I made it, but only in ACTIVE application. So, if you open your mini-app, then it is possible to handle bluetooth status events (see the picture). Couldn't apply it in the background yet :-(.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Pavel I'm wondering where did you get those `@zos/...` packages with the zeppOS definitions, is it yours? Any plans to make them available on npm?

Comment: @Leu, It's from oficial docs. https://docs.zepp.com/docs/reference/device-app-api/newAPI/ble/?_highlight=ble

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do a little hack to poll the Bluetooth connection to achieve the desired behavior, but first let's understand why.

Per ZeppOS architectural decision, **your app will never run in background on the device**. I believe this is for battery efficiency reasons or even available processing power.

With that in mind, We'll use `hmApp.alarmNew` and `hmApp.alarmCancel` in order to get it working, as follows:

1. Create a new `page` that will be responsible for checking the bluetooth connection, something like `page/connectionCheck.js` and declare it in your `app.json` target (you can also use the default `index.js` if you want)
2. In the `onInit()` of the page, register a new `hmApp.alarm` and cancel the existing ones if needed to avoid waking up the app unnecessarily
3. In the `build()` call, verify if it's connected to the cellphone using the `hmBle.connectStatus()` and alert the user.

Summarizing, it'll look like this:
(I'm using zeppOS API v1.0 here to make it work on all devices)

```js
const WAKE_UP_INTERVAL_SECONDS = 30 // this value must be higher than the screen on time on app
const POLL_ALARM_PREF_ID = 'my_bluetooth_poll_alarm'

const vibrate = hmSensor.createSensor(hmSensor.id.VIBRATE)

Page({
  onInit(param) {
    vibrate.stop() // stop any vibration
    vibrate.scene = 27 // set the vibration scene to 27 (1000ms vibration, high intensity)

    // verify if this launch was triggered by an alarm or not
    if(param === POLL_ALARM_PREF_ID) { 
      const existingAlarm = hmFS.SysProGetInt(POLL_ALARM_PREF_ID) // get existing alarm reference from system preferences
      if(existingAlarm) {
        // cancel existing alarm
        hmApp.alarmCancel(existingAlarm)
      }
    }

    // always create a new alarm to avoid alarm trigger while using the app
    const alarm = hmApp.alarmNew({
      file: 'pages/connectionCheck',
      appid: 123123, // <YOU APP ID HERE>
      delay: WAKE_UP_INTERVAL_SECONDS,
      param: POLL_ALARM_PREF_ID
    })

    hmFS.SysProSetInt(POLL_ALARM_PREF_ID, alarm) // Save new alarm reference on system preferences
  },
  build() {
    if(hmBle.connectStatus() === true) {
      // Do something if already connected, maybe return to the home screen, exit the program or even turn the sreen off
      hmApp.exit()
    } else {
      // show a message to the user / vibrate the watch
      vibrate.start()
    }
  },
  onDestroy() {
    vibrate && vibrate.stop() // stop any vibration
  }
})
```

Comment: Hi Leu, this solution have been very usefull for me. Thanks.